# Requesting certain extended permissions (read_stream) in facebook login not working

Tags: facebook, oauth, facebook-javascript-sdk

My goal is to have my app be able to read my users stream using the extended permission "read_stream" , however when requesting that permission the dialog doesn't show me having requesting that permission.

I have no trouble requesting the email, or publish_actions permissions, but read_stream is a no go as well as other various extended permissions. Here is an example of what I am using for the facebook login:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?scope=publish_actions%2Cread_stream&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.MYDOMAIN.com%2Fsocialregistration%2Ffacebook%2Fconnect%2F&display=popup&client_id=MYAPPID
```

Is there another permission I need to request when requesting read_stream ?  Is there something I need to change in my facebook app settings specifically for the scope permission request?  My goal is to be able to get permission for "read_stream".

Thank you for any input!

Answer (score 0):

The method I describe does work! The issue was that there is a second facebook prompt for the extended permissions that occurs AFTER the initial prompt for permissions.

What is confusing is that facebook shows permissions for email and publish_actions on the first facebook dialog box instead of in a consistant manner for all the extended permissions....but that's facebook's choice!

So hopefully this helps anybody else that was confused like me!